# Google Chrome 20 and unload event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I need to execute some JavaScript code when user try to close the page, and I know that in google chrome `unload` event is not always fired. I tried some workaround but from last update (chrome 20.0.xxx) nothing seems to work.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    ...
}

window.onpagehide = function() {
    ...
}
```

Is there another way (without using an external library)?

Comment: You know, there's a *reason* my browser doesn't let you do that.

Comment: @GregHewgill: And yet all major browsers (except Opera, admittedly) have supported `unload` and `beforeunload` events for over a decade and haven't removed them, probably because the're useful. No browser allows script to do the obvious evil of preventing the user from leaving the page.

Comment: I'm sure about that, but is there a way to fire some event before user close browser? I want a behaviour like a desktop application where on exit a popup could eventually ask "are you sure to exit without save your work?"

Comment: The following HTML works fine for me in Chrome 20: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script>window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) { return "REALLY?"; };</script></head></html>`. Are you using an iframe?

Comment: @TimDown Re your first comment, Opera supports `beforeunload` since version 12, which was released last month.

Comment: @RobW: Right, thanks. About time.